# Github Page deployment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I recently completed my first project that integrates html, css, and javascript. When I deployed the website to github pages, the site generated looks like the html file is not communicating with the css and js files.

When I run the index.html file on my local machine, it works just fine on the mozilla and safari browsers. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Here is a link to the github repository [My Github Repository](https://github.com/Xavier-Julian-Rodriguez/OrlandoDateGenerator)

[Here is what the site is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPjuz.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your repository the files are in the same directory as the index.html, so:

instead of `<script src="./javaScript/script.js"></script>`

import like this:`<script src="/script.js"></script>`

Doing `/script.js` is the same as
`https://xavier-julian-rodriguez.github.io/OrlandoDateGenerator/script.js`

To check if you are importing correctly try to access the file from the url: https://xavier-julian-rodriguez.github.io/OrlandoDateGenerator/script.js

Comment: Thank you Briuor! I went back and made the edits as you suggested. The index.html works like it was intended. Thanks again! I learned a few things from your post. :-)